# Android Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, sqlite, gradle

Me sale este error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

He probado probado `Clean project y Rebuild project`.
Mi App tiene una base de datos interna y contiene  *1.700 imágenes*. ¿Puede ser ese el problema? que tenga demasiada imágenes para ser interna.

El gradle que uso es:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

Comment: Como ayuda podría comentarte que tuve que pasar por el mismo error. En mi caso encontré la solución en que había una imagen corrupta que Android no podía abrir. (También decirte que ese error puede ser causado por varias cosas)

Comment: Le quite las ultimas imágenes metidas y le estado modificando as JPG que daban problemas por jpg y sigue igual.

Comment: pero tienes guardadas las imagenes dentro de la base de datos o dentro de drawable?

Comment: dentro de drawable, esta hecho con SQLite